# check array item's value by looping

Tags: php, mysql

```
while ($row = $checkUser->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr = $row['username'];
}
```

check like this just don't work

```
if($arr !="john"){

}else{

}
```

how can I check $row['username'] contain or not string "john"?

Comment: You mean `if($arr !="john"){` or is that `$arry` just a typo?

Comment: By the looks of my upvotes, I doubt it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that's just a typo...

Comment: Well, good luck to the person who put in an "answer" then @bwoebi seems like it was a typo from the OP's edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- see, the user did himself update the question. It really just was a typo in the question.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my comment above @bwoebi Which is why I always like to comment first and not have to ask questions later ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presumming that you are getting this `$row['username']` right. then

```
$arr = array();

while ($row = $checkUser->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row['username'];
}

if(in_array("john",$arr)){
    //there is a username john in the array
}else{
    //this is no john inside the array
}
```

Comment: I don't want to put into while, possible? coz if $arr = john, I want to do my another sql query execution.

Comment: aah i get it you mean to check if `$arr` contain the string `john`?

Comment: @user3522474 i updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array